# Как задать размер новому окну?

Tags: javascript

Как задать размер нового окна? а так же его центровку

```
<a href="javascript:open_window(''cart.php?addproduct={$product_info.productID}{counter name='select_counter_hidden' start=0 skip=1 print=false}{counter name='select_counter_hidden_extra' start=0 skip=1 print=false}{section name=i loop=$product_extra}{if $product_extra[i].option_type eq 1}{section name=s loop=$product_extra[i].option_show_times}&option_select_hidden_{counter name=select_counter_hidden}='+document.HiddenFieldsForm.option_select_hidden_{counter name=select_counter_hidden_extra}.value+'{/section}{/if}{/section}&count='+document.MainForm.totalcount.value+'',400,300);" ')">открыть</a>
```

Comment: нужно указать _'много параметров'_. А еще определить функцию: *open_window*

Comment: ну вот же указываются: `400,300`

Comment: @Grundy меняю эти значения и ничего не изменяется

Comment: что за функция `open_window` и какие ей все-таки параметры в итоге передаются? не шаблонное непонятно что, а конечная строка? В каком браузере проверял?

Comment: Попробуйте начать со стандартного [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).